# How to save YOLO detection class names in a csv file

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolo

I started learning Computer Vision with YOLOv4 for one of my projects on detecting fashion objects from videos. I have trained the model with a custom dataset and now want to save the detected object names in a csv file for further analysis. How do I write a python function to save the detected class names from the video in CSV/txt file. I wrote a python function with flag as csv, but it didn't work.

```
if FLAGS.csv:
    #Capturing class names into csv file
    import csv
    crop_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'detections', 'crop', video_name)
    try:
        os.mkdir(crop_path)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    with open('class_detections.csv','w',newline ='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        counted_classes = count_objects(pred_bbox, by_class = False, allowed_classes=allowed_classes)
        #Loop through dict and print
        for key, value in counted_classes.items():
            str = key
            data = allowed_classes 
            writer.writerow(data)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And also be very clear on "it didn't work", we cannot guess what happens when you run the code.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i meant, it didn't show any output which i was expecting. it just showed the detections but didn't extract the class names into the list